# Linux Kernel Module - Sharing variables between source files

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to link a kernel module to a non-LKM source file. The problem is, I'm running into some issues. The names of the two files are chardev.c (the LKM) and foo.c.

My Makefile:

```
obj-m += chardev.o
obj-y += foo.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
    $(CC) test.c -o test
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
    rm test
```

Inside of chardev.c I've the following line of code: `extern int foo;`, and inside foo I've the following line of code: `int foo = 123;`. (Both lines are at file-scope.)

When running make I'm getting the following output:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/build/ M=/home/kylemart/Desktop/Device-Driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/kylemart/Desktop/Device-Driver/chardev.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "foo" [/home/kylemart/Desktop/Device-Driver/chardev.ko] undefined!
  CC      /home/kylemart/Desktop/Device-Driver/chardev.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/kylemart/Desktop/Device-Driver/chardev.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
cc test.c -o test
```

Seems things aren't linking properly. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

This seems to work, but there's a problem:

```
obj-m += chardev.o
chardev-objs += foo.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
    $(CC) test.c -o test
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
    rm test
```

Although it compiles without warnings, after installing the compiled module (i.e. `sudo insmod chardev.ko`) there isn't a new device present in `/dev`. Previously, without trying to link source files, installing kernel modules as previously stated created a device file. That said, the device is present when running `lsmod`.

Comment: you are probably missing `EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo)`

Comment: @ensc Tried that and it didn't seem to make a difference while using either of the above Makefile implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `all` target builds only the module, but not the kernel so that the `foo` symbol does not exist there.

When compiling a source (here: `foo.c`) into the kernel, you have to integrate the makefile into the kernel source.  E.g. you have to add

```
obj-y += my-driver/
```

to the makefile in the previous directory and build the whole kernel.  You should probably remove your `all:` and `clean:` targets from the makefile to avoid conflicts with kernel builtin rules.

`foo.c` must contain

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo);
```

or

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(foo);
```

### The second makefile...

will generate only the `chardev.ko` module which is built from only `foo.c`; `chardev.c` will not be used for it.  When you really want this, you have to change file names; e.g.

```
obj-m += chardev.o
chardev-objs = chardev-core.o foo.o
```

Comment: Thanks! So when creating a module from multiple source files, none of the file names should match module name