# Linux Kernel Module - Producing two modules with shared local header

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have the following files: `buffer.c`, `buffer.h`, `chardevin.c`, `chardevout.c` and `Makefile`. Both `chardevin.c` and `chardevout.c` are kernel modules. Both kernel modules include `buffer.h`, which is implemented by `buffer.c`. Ideally, I'd like the makefile to make both kernel modules while linking the buffer implementation (i.e. produce chardevin.ko and chardevout.ko). I can't seem to figure this part out...

Here's the contents of my `Makefile`:

```
obj-m += chardevin.o chardevout.o
obj-y += buffer.c

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
```

I get the following as output, however:

```
kylemart@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/build/ M=/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
  CC [M]  /mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevin.o
  CC [M]  /mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevout.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 2 modules
WARNING: "buffer_read" [/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevout.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "buffer_length" [/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevout.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "buffer_write" [/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevin.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "buffer_length" [/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevin.ko] undefined!
  CC      /mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevin.mod.o
  LD [M]  /mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevin.ko
  CC      /mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevout.mod.o
  LD [M]  /mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevout.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
```

Here's the contents of `buffer.h`:

```
#ifndef BUFFER_H
#define BUFFER_H

ssize_t buffer_write(const char *src, size_t n);
ssize_t buffer_read(char *dest, size_t n);
size_t buffer_length(void);

#endif
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Changed "buffer.c" to "buffer.o" in the Makefile. Here's the output:

```
kylemart@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/build/ M=/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 2 modules
WARNING: "buffer_read" [/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevout.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "buffer_length" [/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevout.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "buffer_write" [/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevin.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "buffer_length" [/mnt/hgfs/ucf-os-linux/SplitDriverWithMutex/chardevin.ko] undefined!
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux Kernel Module - Sharing variables between source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700578/linux-kernel-module-sharing-variables-between-source-files)

Answer (score 0):

Replace as below this:

`obj-y += buffer.c -- > obj-y += buffer.o`

Comment: Whoops! Fixed, but that still hasn't resolved all of the issues. Running into the issues I've appended to the original post.

Comment: Try `obj-y += buffer.o 
bj-m += chardevin.o chardevout.o`

Comment: That didn't produce any kernel objects :(

Comment: That's wired, really i can't think of it.

Comment: Do I need to use EXPORT_SYMBOL in this situation?